# function got undefined. Basic program

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new at this. Looked at different examples but still cannot figure what is wrong with my code

index.html

```
<html ng-app="main">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        {{3 + 2}}
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {

    angular.module("main", [])
        .controller("MainController", MainController);

    var MainController = function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello Angular!";
    };
}());
```

Comment: cant see any error in your code.check your path for javascript files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'MainController' got undefined because it called before it declare.

solution: declare 'MainController' before it call.

```
(function() {
  var MainController = function($scope) {
      $scope.message = "Hello Angular!";
  };

  angular.module("main", [])
    .controller("MainController", MainController);
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you open up your console (`Ctrl-Shift-I` in Chrome), you'll most likely see an error message with a URL like `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/ng/areq?p0=MainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`, which reports

> Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined

So you can either change move `var MainController = function($scope)...` to the top to define it before using it in the `controller` function or change it to a function definition `function MainController($scope)...`, which gets hoisted to the top.

The [*Controller as*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example) method is much more preferred these days. So take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9ghC0?p=preview) to see your example reworked. Good luck with AngularJs, it's quite fun =)

Comment: Haha thank you so much. I barely just got started with AngularJS for work. Thinking of cramming a lot of tutorials on plural sight since I purchased an account recently and starting with the beginner ones and this is what I was taught. I'm sure as I go further through the videos, they will cover more recent conventions

Comment: I am looking at the code and had a question. Using the 'Controller as' method of doing things, is passing $scope even necessary anymore?

Comment: For the most part, it isn't. Unless you need functions like `$scope.$on` or watches.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainController` definition should be placed before you create the module